# How to apply DEFAULT style for all the project

Tags: delphi, firemonkey-style

I work with VCL and FMX on this application, we are updating pack by pack of the software to FMX.

Something I did on the code, changed the STYLE of the application.
On the design view, it is the DEFAULT style, without any style edition.

However, when the application is compiled the STYLE for all FMX forms are changed, and the screen become a mess, the buttons disappears, etc...

I don't know what has been done to achieve it, but I could not find a manner to set all project to DEFAULT LAYOUT.

I tried to use

```
TStyleManager.SetStyleFromFile('light.style')
```

using the samples from delphi folder.

However, noon of the .STYLE are the DEFAULT.

Is there any DEFAULT.STYLE?

Or any manner to set DEFAULT.STYLE on RUNTIME?

Comment: Simply: `TStyleManager.SetStyle(nil);`